# Parsing multilevel text list

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need to parse text lists:

```
1 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item

2 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item

3 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item
```

I was trying to use regular expression to split first level list:

```
import re
def re_show(pat, s):
 print re.compile(pat, re.S).sub("{\g<0>}", s),'\n'

s = '''
1 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item

2 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item

3 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item
'''

re_show('\n\d+.*?(?=\n\n\d+.*?\n\n)', s)
```

But it doesn't work. Instead of this:

```
{
1 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item}
{
2 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item}
{
3 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item}
```

I've got this:

```
{
1 List name}
{
1 item
2 item
3 item}
{
2 List name}
{
1 item
2 item
3 item}

3 List name

1 item
2 item
3 item
```

What would you recommend to solve this task?

**Thanks for your answers**. I've learned many new features of Python.

I think, I will use "state machine" approach as described [here](http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/chap4.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ListParser:

 def __init__(self, s):
  self.str = s.split("\n")
  print self.str
  self.answer = []

 def parse(self):
  self.nextLine()
  self.topList()
  return

 def topList(self):
  while(len(self.str) > 0):
   self.topListItem()

 def topListItem(self):
  l = self.nextLine()
  print "TOP: " + l
  l = self.nextLine()
  if l != '':
   raise Exception("expected blank line but found '%s'" % l)
  sub = self.sublist()

 def nextLine(self):
  return self.str.pop(0)

 def sublist(self):
  while True:
   l = self.nextLine()
   if l == '':
    return # end of sublist marked by blank line
   else:
    print "SUB: " + l

parser = ListParser(s)
parser.parse() 
print "done"
```

prints

```
TOP: 1 List name
SUB: 1 item
SUB: 2 item
SUB: 3 item
TOP: 2 List name
SUB: 1 item
SUB: 2 item
SUB: 3 item
TOP: 3 List name
SUB: 1 item
SUB: 2 item
SUB: 3 item
done
```

Comment: Your solution put an idea to my head to use "State Machine" approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have control over the list format? With just a little editing, you could turn that into config file format, and use the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module.

Otherwise, how about with a little recursion?

```
from collections import defaultdict

def fill_data(data, key, sequence, pred):
    """Recursively fill the data dictionary"""
    for item in sequence:
        # if the pred is true, add it to the list
        if pred(item):
            data[key].append(item)
        # otherwise recurse, with item as key
        else:
            return fill_data(data, item, sequence, pred)
    return data

# a key->list dictionary
data = defaultdict(list)
# Get the text as a sequence of non-empty lines
lines = (l for l in s.splitlines() if l.strip())

def is_data_line(line):
    """Is this line a data line (i.e. two items)?"""
    return len(line.split()) == 2

result = fill_data(data, None, lines, is_data_line )

print dict(result)
```

**Output (prettified)**:

```
{'2 List name': 
    ['1 item', '2 item', '3 item'], 
 '3 List name': 
    ['1 item', '2 item', '3 item'], 
 '1 List name': 
    ['1 item', '2 item', '3 item']}
```

Comment: No, I haven't. I need to transform this format to another (lists are very long, this is just little example)

Your code is working well but I didn't understand it yet (I'm newbie:)) Thank you!

Comment: You're right, the code is a bit cryptic. Thanks for pointing it out. I've added some comments that I hope will make what it does clearer.

Answer (score 1):

here's one way using dictionary

```
f=open("myfile")
d={}
e=0
for line in f:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if "List" in line:
      e=e+1
      d.setdefault(e,[])
    d[e].append(line)
f.close()
for i ,j in d.iteritems():
    print i,j
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm newbie in Python. I didn't know about dictionaries. Very similar to associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I'm missing the point, but isn't this simply a question of looking for `List`?

Comment: No, "List name" could be any string